# Determining Qt stylesheet options programmatically?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

Is it possible to look up stylesheet values at runtime in Qt?

I'm working on a custom button derived from `QPushButton` that has some stylesheet properties set. I'd like to be able to look up some stylesheet settings like border width, `margin`, `padding-top`, `padding-left`, `padding-right`, etc.  Is this at all possible to do without calling `widget->getStyleSheet()` and parsing out the values myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think so, you might be able to find something by stepping through the drawing code. But the parsing and the application of stylesheets is pretty optimised and uses a lot of preprocessing. I don't even think that you can get to the stylesheet of a widget if it was actually set in a parent.

Answer (score 5):

Internally, when you call QApplication::setStyleSheet() Qt creates a QStyle sub-class called QStyleSheetStyle.

That means you can query style sheet information via the normal QStyle methods. Just remember to fill in the options and widget parameters properly to ensure you get the right values from the style sheet.

Comment: Well this is archeology win but... can you drop an example or something? How can you use QStyle get a widget CSS property?

Comment: How do I query the QSS properties in the item delegates paint method?